# Extracting items from 2d List

Tags: python

I have one 2d list splited_body:

```
splited_body= [
 ['startmsg', 'This is a test massage.', 'endmsg\r\n'], 
 ['startmsg', 'Hi There is some issue in the process.', '5', 'F3', 'D1', '2', 'endmsg\r\n']
]
```

I want to print all data before 'endmsg' and I am using for and if combination as below:

```
for i in range(len(splited_body)):
    for j in range(len(splited_body[i])):
        if splited_body[i][j] == 'endmsg':
            break
        x = splited_body[i][j]
        print(x)
```

But it is printing all items in the list. How can I do that. Please someone tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're looking for "endmsg" on the third line, but in the splited_body data, it's "endmsg\r\n", which means that it will never match.

Comment: Is `endmsg` not always going to be the last element in the list?

Comment: try it : li = [item for it in splited_body for item in it if item.strip() != 'endmsg']

Comment: Thank you @Scovetta after adding \r\n it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `startswith`:

```
for b in splited_body:
    for i in b:
        if i.startswith('endmsg\r\n'):
            break
        print(i)
```

Comment: Not a good idea. It will also break for a string like `'endmsg psuedo'`.

Comment: Put the complete `'endmsg\r\n'`, no other messages can possibly have it.

Comment: Still it will break for `'endmsg\r\n psuedo'`.

Comment: It's against the requirements of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Using `in` keyword you can iterate individual elements in a list. So you can try this out:

```
for body in splited_body:
    for msg in body:
        if msg.strip() == 'endmsg':
            break
        print(msg)
```

Comment: I'd vote to `.strip()` the message instead

Comment: @DillonDavis, thanks for the suggestion. `.strip()` is indeed required.

Answer (score 0):

Python removes last element from list by [:-1].

```
for items in splited_body:
    print(items[:-1])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please include an explanation with your example